# Code does not verify validation or loop properly

Tags: c, validation, while-loop

> Use a while loop.
>   Prompt a user to input a site’s expenditure and upon hitting the return key:
>
> Ask if they want to add another expenditure with the options of "Y" or "N" (as long as the "continue_loop" variable is equal to "Y"). (Hint: The loop should end if the user input is anything but "Y".)
>
> Validate that the data entered is not below zero (review Chapter 4, Program 4-16 to see an example of input validation). If the value is below 0, present a message that says "Values must be greater than 0."

Originally coded in python the code now has to be redone in C. I'm pretty bad at coding normally though I was decent at python.

I have most of the code down and was able to have it work fine in non-loop form but I cant figure out the while loop setup to have it verify a y/n response.
At the core I need the following for loops and validation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int site[20]={};

    int i = 0;

    int sum;

    int loop;

    int n;

    float avg;

    char continue_loop = "y";

    printf("Enter Site Expenditure:  \n");
    scanf(" %d",(site+i));
    ++i;
    printf("Do you want to enter another expenditure? Y/N \n");
    scanf(" %c",&continue_loop);

    while (continue_loop == "y");
    {
    printf("Enter Site Expenditure:  \n");
    scanf(" %d",(site+i));
    ++i;
    printf("Do you want to enter another expenditure? Y/N \n");
    scanf(" %c",&continue_loop);

    }
    printf("\nSite Expenditures \n");
    for(loop = 0; loop < i; loop++)
    printf(" %d \n", site[loop]);


    sum = avg = 0;

    for(loop = 0; loop < 3; loop++) {
    sum = sum + site[loop];
   }

    avg = (float)sum / loop;
    printf("Average of array values is %.2f ", avg);



    if (avg <= 35000)
    {
        printf ("The average site expenditure is meeting the organization's target goals!");
    }
    else {
        printf("The average site expenditure is NOT meeting the organization's target goals.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try compiling with warnings enabled (`gcc -Wall myprog.c`). Also, understand that in C there is a big difference between `'y'` (a `char` value) and `"y"` (a pointer to a string).

Comment: Ive been working at it for a bit and following examples on several sites but the program ends as soon as a letter is entered instead of looping.

Im not usually a coding guy so this is driving me crazy.

Comment: What if you enter `"No Thanks"` instead of `N` when prompted? Why? How does `scanf` handle extracting character from `stdin`? Why is `fgets()` a preferred way of taking user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things that need to be fixed with your code.
First, when declaring a character literal in C a single ' is used. `char c = 'c';` While a string literal is an array of chars ". `char c[] = "hello";`

Next when using a while loop, if you know the loop has to be executed at least once then a do while is better than a while. With a do while, the condition can be changed inside the loop assuring it to execute at least once.

When validating input, it's just a simple if statement to check if the value is less than 0. In your case we want to make sure that the user only enters positive numbers, if they enter a negative number then they should be asked to enter the number again.

When taking input from a user with scanf, keep in mind that the carriage return is left inside the input stream, the '\n'. So when you take input from the user again, the condition could be satisfied by pulling the last character from the stream and continuing execution in a non blocking fasion. We want to make sure the input stream is cleared after the user enters  some value. There are several ways to do this and I prefer to grab input using fgets but if you are using scanf I just clear the input with `while(getchar()!='\n');`

Lastly, it might be easier to check the value of site using indexing rather tha +i. `site[i]` and when taking input `&site[i]`
Here's the code with the changes I addressed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
    int site[20]={};
    int i = 0;
    int sum;
    int loop;
    float avg;
    char continue_loop = 'y';
    do
    {
        printf("Enter Site Expenditure:  \n");
        do{
            scanf("%d",&site[i]);
            if(site[i]<0){
                printf("enter a value greater than 0\n");
            }
        }while(site[i]<0);

        ++i;
        printf("Do you want to enter another expenditure? Y/N \n");
        while(getchar()!='\n');
        scanf("%c",&continue_loop);

    }while(continue_loop == 'y');

    printf("\nSite Expenditures \n");
    for(loop = 0; loop < i; loop++)
        printf(" %d \n", site[loop]);


    sum = avg = 0;

    for(loop = 0; loop < 3; loop++) {
        sum = sum + site[loop];
    }

    avg = (float)sum / loop;
    printf("Average of array values is %.2f ", avg);



    if (avg <= 35000)
    {
        printf ("The average site expenditure is meeting the organization's target goals!");
    }
    else {
        printf("The average site expenditure is NOT meeting the organization's target goals.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```